# How to correctly round numbers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, math, rounding

As the title suggest i'm expiriencing some issues with rounding numbers. My Script currently looks like this:

```
[uint16]$Product1 = Read-Host "Enter the price of your product: "
...
#$TotalProducts contains the Value from all products together
Write-Host "You spent an amount of $TotalProducts for todays shopping."
```

I want the programm to round the numbers so the total isn't some ridiculous long number. It does work but after i calculated it manually i saw that the programm calculated something else.

The problem here is that the programm rounds for example *122.50* to *122* instead of *123*.

I tried using the following syntax but without success:

```
[math]::Round($Product1)[System.Midpoint.Rounding]::AwayFromZero) = Read-Host "Enter the price of your product: "
```

Am i trying the right thing but i'm butchering the syntax or am i completly wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Read-Host returns a string.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host#systemstring-or-systemsecuritysecurestring)

You should read first, then round the number.

```
$Product1 = Read-Host "Enter the price of your product: "
$RoundedNumber = [math]::Round($Product1, [System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)
```

You now have your rounded value in `$RoundedNumber`.